# _.isEmpty() shows not empty but displays as empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, underscore.js

I'm getting input from the [rateit](https://atmospherejs.com/dandv/jquery-rateit) Meteor package. This package is for displaying and getting star ratings filled out by the user. When I get the the value of a rating that has not been filled out (`var buyUniq =  $(".paymentRate").rateit('value')` )

the value shows as [] (Nothing is there).

`typeof buyUniq` shows that it is an object.

Using JS's Boolean() object wrapper, it returns as true.

```
Boolean(buyUniq)
```

Underscore's _.isEmpty() indicates that the object is not empty (returns false)

```
_.isEmpty(buyUniq)
```

Why does the object show that it is not empty

Comment: **Empty object `{}` is true**. Rather, any non-primitive is **true** even empty.

Comment: How can I check if an object has anything inside it?

Comment: Changing my question a bit ( I think it's ok to do that). I get why it is true but why does underscore _.isEmpty() show that it isn't empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[rateit](https://atmospherejs.com/dandv/jquery-rateit) will show a value as an object if it cannot find the value of the selector.

Ex:

```
var sellUniq = $(".describedRate").rateit('value');
var buyUniq = $(".paymentRate").rateit('value');
```

Where `$(".describedRate")` exists and `$(".paymentRate")` doesn't.

sellUniq will be a number and buyUniq will be an object that is not empty.

Answer (score 2):

An object when converted to Boolean evaluates to true

try this simple

```
var a = {};
Boolean(a);//outputs true
```

> How can I check if an object has anything inside it?

just check if the object has any keys

```
Object.keys(a).length > 0; //if returns true then it has something inside it
```

Comment: The issue is both options return as true with your Object.keys(a).length > 0; when this cant be the case

Comment: @chackerian it is not returning true for me, `var a = {};Object.keys(a).length; Object.keys(a).length > 0;` try this in your console

Answer (score 1):

```
> Boolean([]) // empty array
< true
> Boolean({}) // empty object
< true
```

Array length:

```
myArray.length
```

Object length:

```
Object.keys(myObject).length;
```